# splitting data frame in two parts (w.r.t. NA) and ploting one conditional graph concerning each part

Tags: r, ggplot2

consider the following data frame

```
set.seed(1357)
     DS <- data.frame("group" = c("a", "b", rep(letters[3:6], each=2)),
                      "condition" = c(NA, NA, rep(c("cond1","cond2"), times=4)),
                      "oddsratio" = round(abs(rnorm(10,3)),2),
                      "lower" = round(abs(rnorm(10,0)),2), 
                      "upper" = round(abs(rnorm(10,6)),2))

> DS
   group condition oddsratio lower upper
1      a      <NA>      3.37  0.66  4.59
2      b      <NA>      4.77  0.31  6.37
3      c     cond1      2.02  0.92  5.86
4      c     cond2      3.37  0.71  7.38
5      d     cond1      1.15  0.13  3.30
6      d     cond2      3.74  0.25  7.28
7      e     cond1      2.81  0.89  3.37
8      e     cond2      4.15  1.87  5.32
9      f     cond1      3.22  0.72  4.88
10     f     cond2      2.02  0.54  7.43
```

"lower" and "upper" are lower and upper bound of the confidence interval, respectively.
I want to plot odds ratios with coresponding confidence intervals over groups „a“ to „f“ groupd by „condition“. For two groups of „a“ and „b“ we have `NA` under „condition“. `ggplot` should ignore it and plot odds ratio and confidence interval also for groups „a" and „b“ without considering „condition“. I guess I should split my data frame with respect to the column "condition" and then use `ggplot` for each part but don't know how! Hier is my code, which gives only odds ratios and confidence intervals for group „c“, „d“, „e“ and „f“. I would be thankful for any help.

```
p <- ggplot(DS, aes(x = group, y = oddsratio, color=condition)) +
          theme_bw() +
          geom_point(size = 3, position=position_dodge(.4)) +
          geom_errorbar(aes(x = group, ymin = lower, ymax = upper), position=position_dodge(.4)) +
          scale_color_manual(labels = c("cond1","cond2"), values = c("black","grey"))  +
          labs(x = "Population", 
               y = "Odds Ratio with 95% confidence interval")
p
```

[image]

Comment: You could try replacing the `NA`s with a dummy value. That way the `NA` gets evaluated as a group on its own.

Comment: @Rohit, it seems that doing that, it mess up the dodge options, try to add `DS %>% mutate(condition = ifelse(is.na(condition),'fake','condition')) %>%
ggplot(DS...` in the beginning of the plot. Also manageing it putting in more geom_point (one for `DS[!is.na(DS$condition),]`, one for `DS[is.na(DS$condition),]`), it seems it doesn't like dodgeing. Seems a rather nice question (+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, consider converting the NA values into a new condition such as "NA", then run plot but adjust `scale_color_manual()` to add one more label and value for the new group:

```
DS$condition <- factor(ifelse(is.na(DS$condition), "NA", as.character(DS$condition)))

ggplot(DS, aes(x = group, y = oddsratio, color=condition)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(size = 3, position=position_dodge(.4)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = group, ymin = lower, ymax = upper), position=position_dodge(.4)) +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("cond1","cond2", "NA"), values = c("black","darkgrey", "grey"))  +
  labs(x = "Population", 
       y = "Odds Ratio with 95% confidence interval")
```

[image: Plot Output]